# what is the solution when compiler cannot find user defined datatypes from included .h file?

Tags: c, iar, mqx

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I have a very strange compiler error when I try to compile an example code for USB keyboard device application that I got from Freescale MQX. In usb_descriptor.c it has:

```
`usb_language_t g_usb_language[USB_MAX_SUPPORTED_INTERFACES] =
{
    {
        (uint16_t) 0x0409,
        g_string_descriptors,
        g_string_desc_size
    }
};
/*************************************/
usb_all_languages_t g_languages =
{
    g_usb_str_0,
    sizeof(g_usb_str_0),
    USB_MAX_LANGUAGES_SUPPORTED,
    g_usb_language
};`
```

/******************************/

```
uint8_t USB_Desc_Set_Speed
(
    uint32_t handle,
    uint16_t speed
    )
{
    descriptor_union_t ptr1, ptr2;
UNUSED_ARGUMENT(handle);'
```

`usb_language_t`, `usb_all_languages_t` &  `descriptor_union_t` are defined in usb_desc.h as follows:

```
 typedef struct _usb_language 
{
    uint16_t language_id;
    uint8_t ** lang_desc;
    uint8_t * lang_desc_size;    
} usb_language_t;

typedef struct _usb_all_languages
{
    uint8_t *languages_supported_string;
    uint8_t  languages_supported_size;
    uint8_t  languages_number;
    /*Allocate Memory In App Layer*/
    usb_language_t *usb_language;
} usb_all_languages_t;
typedef union descriptor_union
{
   uint32_t                      word;
   uint8_t *                     bufr;
   void*                         pntr;
   device_descriptor_t         dvic;
   usb_configuration_descriptor_t*  cfig;
   interface_descriptor_t*      intf;
   endpoint_descriptor_t*       ndpt;
   qualifier_descriptor_t*      qual;
   otg_descriptor_t*            otg;
   common_descriptor_t*         common;
} descriptor_union_t;
```

However even after i do `#include "usb_desc.h"`at start of usb_descriptor.c I get error messages that

Error[Pe020]: identifier "usb_language_t" is undefined

Error[Pe020]: identifier "usb_all_languages_t" is undefined

Error[Pe020]: identifier "descriptor_union_t" is undefined

Can someone please help me out with this? I am using IAR for development with MQX 4.0.2 RTOS. Also, I am trying to integrate USB keyboard device application in a pre-existing firmware.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If we are to help, you need to present a [mcve].  We appreciate that you have attempted to minimize the code presented, but it appears that you have minimized the actual problem right out.

Comment: If everything you did present is correct, however, then the most likely explanations are that either the relevant `#include` comes too late, or that the needed declarations are suppressed by conditional compilation directives.

Comment: How do you compile the code, is there some `#if` macros around the typedefs?

Comment: @JohnBollinger You are right! I swapped the relevent #include file to the first place and it worked. Thanks! I will try to be more elaborate from now on.

Comment: @purplepsycho no there was not #if directive. Thanks though..